# Android Studio - V2 Maps - check if polyline intersects other polyline

Tags: android, maps, directions

i am getting a fully loaded map in my android app, and i am getting some directions waypoint using the directions API. What i would like to accomplish now is check if the desired route form A to B intersects with another polyline.
Can someone shed some light into this?
Thank you very much, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

- Loop for each straight line in first polyline
- Loop for each straight line in second polyline
- Test if both straight lines intersect. They both intersects if there exists one point that both line share.

Line equation if endpoints are known:

[image: Straight line equation]